# Нужна ли запятая при однородных определениях?

Tags: определения, прилагательные, пунктуация

Подскажите, нужна ли запятая:

> Минтай свежемороженый непотрошеный с
> головой.

Comment: @Наталья21061990, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум одна запятая всё же нужна:

***Минтай свежемороженый непотрошеный, с головой.***

См. http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114 :

> *§ 39. Запятая ставится при сочетании согласованных и несогласованных
> определений (несогласованное
> определение помещается после
> согласованного)...*

Comment: Слава, запятая не ставится, если сочетание согласованного и несогласованного определения обозначает единый признак: Белая в клеточку скатерть; на ней была синяя в горошек юбка.

Comment: Абсолютно не тот случай. "Непотрошеный, с головой" – не единый признак.

Answer (score 1):

В данном конкретном случае это неоднородные определения. Хотя определения стоят после определяемого существительного( как правило, такие определения однородны), так как в этом положении каждое из них непосредственно связано с определяемым словом и обладает одинаковой смысловой самостоятельностью, например: …Я видел женщину молодую, прекрасную, добрую, интеллигентную, обаятельную (Чехов). 
Отступления от правила встречаются в стихотворной речи, что связано с ритмомелодикой стиха, а также в сочетаниях терминологического характера, где по условиям лексико-семантическим определения даже в положении после определяемого существительного могут быть неоднородными. Например:    - груша зимняя позднеспелая; трубы тонкостенные электросварные нержавеющие; кран мостовой электрический дрейферный.

Ваш пример имеет терминологический характер, именно поэтому определения в нем считаются неоднородными. ***Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь. Д. Э.***

***Дополнение***

***Ответ Граммы.ру***

> Если предложно-падежная форма "с головой" выступает в качестве терминологического определения, то его лучше не отделять от предшествующего определения, так как оно в этом случае приобретает уточняющее значение. Кроме того, отделение несогласованного определения от предшествующего согласованного определения при помощи запятой не имеет обязательного характера. См: Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М., 2009. С. 199.